# Run the orbited server?

Tags: django, comet, orbited

Odd question, but I'm trying to follow this tutorial which explains how to set up comet with django. I'm just confused about some stuff when I'm trying to do the tutorial.

Firstly, where does the orbited.cfg file go? I just placed it at the root of my application (where the settings.py file etc. is). Also, in the cfg, It says to use the localhost address as the http, but I'm not running a development server, can I just put the url I'm using there? What about the port issue?

Secondly, at the end of the tutorial, it says to run the orbited server. How do I do this? Do I need to install orbited beforehand? I ask this also because the html file requires an orbited.js file, and I have no clue where to find that. orbited.org doesn't seem to work. Thank you.

Comment: BTW, I install pyorbited already if people are wondering.

Comment: Okay, well I installed oribted and twisted. And Now I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is no longer relevant for OP, but googlers may find this helpful

```
orbited --config example.cfg
```

where example.cfg is the config file for orbited